# I had completed my JEE Hibernate development, how to deploy my database to production?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I had done the development of my Java EE backend application, which using Hibernate JPA and JAX-RS. Time to deploy into production server.

Currently, the generation of database schema is done by Hibernate JPA, which based on the entities definition, using settings of `hbm2ddl.auto="create"`

I had read a lot of post saying it is a bad idea to have a hbm2ddl.auto settings in persistence.xml, and use SQL instead. However, my application has about 50 entities, with some of them inherit each other.

Is writing a CREATE statement for each tables, relations, sequence tables, the only way to go?

Comment: Now what? Hint: improve the title of your question ...

Comment: I'd expect the database could generate the ddl for you. most places have testing environments where you shake out this kind of thing before it gets to prod.

Comment: @Jägermeister Hint accepted.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks. I found that option in PGAdmin. I am more curious about the persistence.xml settings for JPA 2.1, where 'javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target' not giving me anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you have qualified and well tested your backend, you can dump your database and import this dump (layout only) onto production server.

Future database's evolution should be made with SQL scripts as part of your delivery process.

Comment: So that include the table's sequence, their relations etc, manually?

Comment: here it's what we do for each new table, sequences relations we work we migration scripts that addup to the existing schema. It works well for the past 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the settings like hbm2ddl.auto="create" will be useful in production,just think once you stopped and restart the server,there is a posiblities that It will reset the entire table structure and that could lead to wipe out the entire data's.I have seen some production servers and never seen implemented  hbm2ddl.auto stuff in productions,we can play in testing environments and on our systems not advisable in live stuffs.just written what I knew so far.

Comment: Yup, that's what everyone said. The question is, what should be done to get the database ready? I would like to use db migration tool like Flyway, I can export the schema from PGAdmin, but how do I import into my app?

Comment: We have to use some db tool s that's the only option it will compare the ddl schemas from production and local environment then it will generate a queries, I have used once but forgot the tool name